# How to prove the levi-civita symbol is antisymmetric?

Tags: tensors

I need to prove that the levi-civita symbol is antisymmetric, i.e. $$ε_{ijk}=-ε_{ikj}=-ε_{jik}=-ε_{kji}.$$
I know that by definition this is true, but I don’t know how to go about proving it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of the Levi-Civita symbol?

Comment: ε_{ijk}=0, if at least two indices are the same, ε_{ijk}=1, if  i,j,k are even permutations of 1,2,3 ε_{ijk}=-1, if i,j,k are even permutations of 3,2,1. I think I figured it out, doing what the first answer here suggests! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433917/meaning-and-significance-of-the-levi-civita-symbol